# Comma vs pipe/vertical line in notation for conditional probability

Tags: notation, conditional-probability

What is the difference between the following expressions:

$$P(X_1 < X_2 \mid \min(X_1, X_2) = t) \qquad \text{and}\qquad P(X_1 < X_2,  \min(X_1, X_2) = t)$$

For context, I am trying to understand what it means to say that
 $$P\left(X_1 < X_2 \mid \min(X_1, X_2) = t\right) = \frac{P\left(X_1 < X_2,  \min(X_1, X_2) = t\right)}{P(\min(X_1, X_2)=t)}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read the symbols $\mid$ and $,$ as follows:

1. $"\mid"=$ *given that*. So the LHS can be read as: Probability that $X_1$ is less than $X_2$ **given** that the minimum of $X_1, X_2$ equals $t$.
2. $","=$ *and*. So the RHS (numerator) can be read as: Probability that $X_1$ is less than $X_2$ **and** that the minimum of $X_1, X_2$ equals $t$.

In the first case, it is given/ known/ has already happened that the minimum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is equal to $t$ (and you know it), whereas in the second case you want to find the probability that $X_1<X_2$ and **simultaneously** that the minimum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ equals $t$.

---

In this specific case the RHS (numerator) probability can be simplified to $$P(X_1<X_2, \min\{X_1,X_2\}=t)=P(X_1=t, X_2\ge t)$$ However in most cases the LHS (conditional probability) is easier to calculate.

Comment: So then $P(X=a, Y=b) = P(X=a)P(Y=b)$?

Comment: Only if you know additionally that $X,Y$ are independent. Otherwise no. But presumambly this is the case, or not?

Comment: right. assuming independence. thanks